# Flow union of function types

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I'm working on adding flow types to a JS codebase and have run into some untyped code like this:

```
const doSomething = (callback, type) => {
    if (type === 'one') {
        const bool = callback(42)
    } else if (type === 'two') {
        const str = callback(4, 2)
    }
}
```

The function takes a callback that has one of two signatures, and a type argument which is a string that indicates which signature the callback uses.

In my first attempt to add flow, I've ended up with the following:

```
/* @flow */

type Callback1 = (any) => bool
type Callback2 = (any, any) => string

type WhichFunc = 'one' | 'two'
type Func = Callback1 | Callback2

const test = (func: Func, which: WhichFunc) => {
  if (which === 'one') {
    const b: bool = func(42)
  } else if (which === 'two') {
    const s: string = func(4, 2)
  }
}
```

This fails, unsurprisingly, because flow has no way to verify that the `which` string has any relation to `func`.

Is there a way to add flow types here without changing the API?

Comment: I am confused by the original doSomething function. It doesn't compile for me (missing `=` ?), and it appears to have no return value and no side effects. What is it intended to do?

Comment: It was a simplified example (yes, I was missing the `=`).  The point is it does something and then invokes a callback, but the signature of the callback depends on the type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an explicit (but cumbersome) typecast like this:

```js
const test = (func: Func, which: WhichFunc) => {
  if (which === 'one') {
    const callback: Callback1 = ((func: any): Callback1);
    const b: bool = callback(42);
  } else if (which === 'two') {
    const callback: Callback2 = ((func: any): Callback2);
    const s: string = callback(4, 2)
  }
};
```

You can also see this on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVpK0ctqAuAngA4CmYAwgIYwwBGVAxgNYCMYAvGABQB2ArgFs6pAE4BKTgD4wdOHBgBuAiXLVaDFgCZOPAcLEAaMPpETpYAM75RAS14BzZSrJgA6gAtbjDwDF+vIy6AORwvKTBYAA+YMH4CHDBLuT+gbrq9Exs0ZQ0mdrojGHWYPikJVzcUAGMAFxgqYzGCF4+9Z7efjWSHDIA3qhgYLZQPC2dnBxcoeHBkgNDQ0W8JYx5msz1GRvslVU19VS8hOJb61ms4sqLYMsldPVyCrprGlncACxaV4NgAL5gUgwSzkEZjVoeSbTeKJea-JbFfC3c4sM5vbS6bj7QKHY6nXLo5jfa6LO5Iyz1ax2RwvFHMT7GYm-P6oP6KIA)